# Multi-tenancy support in apache-kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a scenario where multiple clients want to produce and consume messages. Is there a way to achieve *multi-tenancy* in apache kafka so that one client remain intact by a huge inflow of another client.
Basically I want a way to tag client to brokers and all topic/partitions on that client will fall under the tagged brokers.
Here one client produces and consumes messages internally. They are doing this to achieve distributed processing. eg parent message is broken down to children and produces/process these children in any machine them.

Answer (score 0):

One reason that clients would fail from other clients is from I/O saturation on the brokers due to those other clients.

The way to protect from that would be to [enforce quotas](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas).

Not sure I understand what you mean by "tag" since you cannot control partition placement within a cluster, so sending data from particular clients to certain brokers is not possible unless you were to first create a topic then manually re-assign the partiion and replica placements.

Answer (score 0):

By client do you mean a customer tenant? Regardless of that, if the concern is to have a clear load separation between clients(to avoid denial of attack or starvation) one possibility is to have different topics for different clients. This will separate load to some extent(partition based) but not fully as still various resources are shared. Also it has its own de-merits. The demerits are

- The partitions are not shared. If one client is not having enough load and when the partitions are not occupied much with read/write, the partitions are not used for another client in another topic.
- Another pitfall is the number of topics will grow according to number of clients and not according to the message load. Not good again.

Another approach which is probably a better one to avoid denial of attack or starvation of a client is to limit the rate of messages produced(throttle) by a client.